# Epiphany keyboard shortcuts

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts, epiphany

Why some keyboard shortcuts, listed as available, are not working in Epiphany? For example: `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `N` or `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in elementary's patch to remove the app menu. [Here is the bug report.](https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues/17)